# Can't load /root/.rnd into RNG

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I want to generate a server certificate using Windows Open SSL.

When I run this command line, it appear this error. What should I do?

Command

```
:
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

Error:

`Can't load ./.rnd into RNG 10504:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:crypto\rand\randfile.c:98:Filename=./.rnd`

I also try to find openssl config file, but no, I don't have that file.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try removing or commenting `RANDFILE = $ENV::HOME/.rnd` line in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

Comment: how about if I don't have that file?

Comment: So not using that file removing that option

Comment: It seems to be safe: [OpenSSL issue: "Can't load ./.rnd into RNG"](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7754#issuecomment-444063355).

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem when using the OpenVPN Road Warrior script on Ubuntu 18.04.

The solution was to create the file *manually*, after that the script worked perfectly.

First cd to the right directory. Then create the file yourself by calling openssl and telling it to produce random bytes with **rand** and to write to a file called **.rnd** using the **-writerand** option, as follows

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki
openssl rand -writerand .rnd
```

For more info see openssl man page https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-rand.html

Comment: This seems the easiest solution, worked for me! I wasn't keen to modify a config file I didn't much understand.

Answer (score 8):

The reason:
"the -rand" option tells by default to use random file .rnd somewhere in your OS.
Since user issues to use .rnd file which does not exist!!!!

Remedy:
add -writerand to write the .rnd file if does not exist.

For Example:

```
root@CentOS:/usr/local/etc/openldap/private # openssl genrsa -rand -genkey -out cert.key 2048
Can't load -genkey into RNG
546983936:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file:/usr/src/crypto/openssl/crypto/rand/randfile.c:98:Filename=-genkey
```

After adding -writerand

```
root@CentOS:/usr/local/etc/openldap/private # openssl genrsa -writerand -genkey -out cert.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
...........................+++++
..............+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
root@CentOS:/usr/local/etc/openldap/private #
```

I myself will bump into this error again. And ofcourse I will check StackOverflow ( R6000 ha ha ) first!!!

Comment: Ref: got the idea from here: https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua-pki/issues/7

Comment: For some reason running this command a second time results in the error the OP reported : (